Create a new verb from a noun (for wordplay)
In English it is quite easy to do this — you simply add a to in front of the noun and you suddenly have a verb. Add a y and you have an adjective.
For example:

fox -> to fox -> foxy

What does to fox mean? I do not know, but it works linguistically and invites you to play with language.
How do you do this in Italian? For example with gufo?

You can often invent a 1st conjugation verb in -are (you might for instance ask Vogliamo cinemare? to suggest going to a cinema, and most people would understand); in some cases you might use the -eggiare suffix (Non marcelleggiare might mean “don't do as Marcello does” to Marcello's friends).
A verb from gufo is an unfortunate example, since gufare is an existing verb for both emitting the owl's verse and, colloquially, bringing bad luck. Volpare o volpeggiare don't exist, but might conceivably be used in a context that made their meaning clear.
For adjectives, a notoriously fertile suffix is -oso. In a famous 1983 series of ads for the then new Fiat Uno car, it was defined with such newly created adjectives as “sciccosa”, “comodosa”, “scattosa” and “risparmiosa”. (And I spare you the more recent controversies about the adjective “petaloso”.)
